# how to use 7zxr.dll for uncompress files?

Tags: c++, compression, 7zip

[image: none]

I have compiled two files, 7.dll and 7.lib. How to use them to uncompress files in C++? I heard that 7Z uses a COM interface, but I don’t understand this interface at all, so please be as detailed as possible for the answer. Thank you very much.